# Question of finding the weakest proposition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

could you help me solve this question?

We consider three propositions, $P,Q,R$. We want to find the $R$ that satisfies the following conditions:

a) $P\implies R$ ,

b) $(Q\land R)  \implies P$

c) $¬(R\implies  Q)$

d) $¬(Q\implies  R)$

e) Among all the propositions $R$ that can satisfy the conditions, we want to choose the logically weakest statements such that (a)-(d) hold.

My question is this: A statement $A$ is logically weaker thank $B$ iff $A$ is implied by $B$ but $A$ does not imply $B$.

Given this, we know that  $(Q\implies P)$ could be a good candidate for satisfying a (a) - (d), Since for every $R$ that satisfy the conditions, it holds that $R\implies $ $(Q\implies P)$.

How can we prove that for all $R$ that satisfy the conditions above, $(Q\implies P)$ does not imply any $R$ that implies it, a part from $(Q\implies P)$.

Answer (score 1):

$Q \implies P$ is only $\mathbf{false}$ when $Q$ is $\mathbf{true}$ and $P$ is $\mathbf{false}$ . So the only weaker truth function of $P$ and $Q$ is the one that is $\mathbf{true}$ for all values of $P$ and $Q$, which doesn't satisfy conditions (b) and (d).

Comment: Thanks, I think it is more clear. This allows us to say that $Q⟹P$ is the one implied by all the other R. Isn't it necessary to state that there are no $R$ implied by $Q⟹P$ to say that it is the weakest formula? How does one prove it?

Comment: $A$ is weaker than $B$ if $B \implies A$ is $\mathbf{true}$, which in truth table terms, means $A$ has  $\mathbf{true}$. wherever $B$ has  $\mathbf{true}$ (but $A$ may also have  $\mathbf{true}$ where $B$ has $\mathbf{false}$). As $Q \implies P$ has only one $\mathbf{false}$, the only weaker truth function is the one that is $\mathbf{true}$ requardless of $P$ and $Q$.